# Sitecore Web Forms For Marketers language versioning

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

Sitecore.NET 6.4.1 (rev. 111003) , web Forms For Marketers 2.2.0 rev.111104.

Placing a form on an English (en) version of an item causes display of Submit button and complex type fields (password confirm, credit card) on  other language versions, even when no version of the form exists in that language. Simple type fields are apparently unaffected. The label values for the fields displayed seem to come from the English default values in the WFFM settings, not the English version of the form.

Has anyone else had this problem, and has anyone found a solution to it?

Comment: Are you trying to translate the form in other languages, or have it hidden in other languages?

Comment: I want it hidden in other languages until fully translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Sitecore support have confirmed this as a bug, and have provided an alternative ascx file for the WFFM form display.